# Plotting cumulative distributions with y-axis scaled to normal distribution in R

Tags: r, plot, cumulative-frequency

This is the first time I have a R question that I couldn't find on Stack Overflow already - forgive me if the reason why I didn't find anything is a specific term for the type of thing I'm looking for that I'm not aware of (is there?).

I'd like to display data as a cumulative frequency. Since my focus is more on the edges of the Distribution, it is helpful to scale the y-axis to a normal distribution. The result should look something like this: 
[image]

I've read about quantile-quantile plots, but honestly I can't figure out how to apply them if I want to preserve the X-axis.

I tried both `base` graphics and `ggplot2`, but can't figure it out. My current solution is therefore, for example

```
plot(ecdf(trees$Volume))
```

or

```
ggplot(data=trees, aes(Volume)) + stat_ecdf()
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like this: `plot(trees$Volume, cumsum(dnorm(trees$Volume, mean = mean(trees$Volume), sd = sd(trees$Volume))))`?

Comment: Hmm, no, the solution doesn't work - the shape of the curve is approximately ok, but at the same time the y axis is still linear and the order of the values seems incorrect. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `scales` package and the `probability_trans()` function:

Without transforming the y scales:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = trees,
       aes(Volume)) + 
    stat_ecdf()
```

[image]

With transformation of y axis:

```
ggplot(data = trees,
       aes(Volume)) + 
    stat_ecdf() + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::probability_trans("norm"))
```

[image]

You can read more about these in the documents with `?probability_trans`.
The `probability_trans()` function takes standard R probability names to scale your axis with.
You can also create a new transformation with `trans_new()` if you need something completely custom.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much it. With `breaks = c(...)` and a specified `ylim` via `coord_cartesian()` I get exactly the same y axis as in my example above.

Comment: @Bearheart great. Glad to hear I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The `qpplot.das` function from the `StatDA` package by Peter Filzmoser might be a "`base` R" way for you.

```
library(StatDA) 
qpplot.das(trees$Volume, qdist = qnorm, xlab = "Volume", line = FALSE)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1znBP.png)

The StatDA package was used for all calculations and graphics for the book *Statistical Data Analysis Explained* by Reimann, Filzmoser, Garret and Dutter. All [R scripts](http://file.statistik.tuwien.ac.at/StatDA/R-scripts) are online, also examples for [the QP plots](http://file.statistik.tuwien.ac.at/StatDA/R-scripts/page112.html).